# Titan/Cassandra Connection Issues in Docker Only

Tags: cassandra, docker, titan

I'm running Titan 1.0.0 and Cassandra 2.1.

When starting cassandra and titan locally, I don't run into any issues. However, when I start cassandra and titan in separate docker containers and try to link them together, I'm unable to do so and I receive a timeout:

```
 [host=X.X.X.X(X.X.X.X):9160, latency=10005(10005), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
```

Here's the Dockerfile for the api:

```
FROM java:8
ADD config config
ADD target/api-1.1.jar api.jar
EXPOSE 7000-7001 7199 8080 9042 9160
CMD ["java", "-jar", "api.jar"]
```

and here are the commands that I'm using to start the containers

```
docker run -d --name cs1 cassandra:2.1
docker run -d --name api --link cs1:cs1 -p 8080:8080 api
```

Any insight as to what I might be doing incorrectly with my docker setup?

Comment: May sound silly, but did you rebuild from the Dockerfile after making any changes to the EXPOSE?

Comment: I did indeed. I've made that silly mistake too many times, though - thanks for the thought.